# python BeautifulSoup parse html get the charset of html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have three html files and thire charset is gb2312

the docment of BeautifulSoup says BeautifulSoup get the charset from html to decode the html to unicode

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

the deocding should be gb2312
but  why i get the originaldecoding is windows-1251?because of this the ouput is error

Comment: You could try: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, from_encoding='gb2312')` if you're sure it's correct and needs to be over-ridden... But - what do you mean by wrong? What do you mean by output?

Comment: Thank you ! I want to get the tables from these html files.Their charset maybe is gb2312,maybe utf-8.The wrong means when i use BeautifulSoup to parse the html file with the charset is gb2312,but the BeautifuleSoup get windows-1251 to decode the html file ,so that the content of the tables (my output) is error.